# How to find linear equation from text

Tags: linear-algebra

A company produces covers for cell phones. The costs of a production of $x$ units can be described by a linear function $C(x)=ax+b$.
At a production of $150$ units the costs are DKK $6000$.
At a production of $200$ units the costs are DKK $7500$.

Find an equation for $C$

Comment: i can't get my head around this, how should i start?

Comment: solve the system of linear equations by using your two given Points

Answer (score 0):

The first statement tells you $C(150) = 6000$, or $150 a + b = 6000$. The second statement tells you $C(200) = 7500$ or $200 a + b = 7500$.

Now, use linear combinations or substitution to solve the two equations together to get $a,b$.